# Qt + OpenGL + OpenCV - Display a nested 3D scene in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, opencv

I want to do a simple Qt window with some buttons for user interaction and have a 3D scene inside this window and through this buttons, the user will configure and run the OpenCV software to analyze the image and take some decisions.

I already have the Qt software part running and  my doubts are now with respect to OpenGL.

As far as I had read, Qt own implementation of OpenGL (QGLWidget) is not a full implementation of OpenGL, but more like a OpenGL ES 2.0 for increased cross platform support. I don't want to lose any OpenGL functionality since this is an exercise for future projects so is it possible to use full OpenGL and still have it shown inside Qt? And will I be able to provide this 3D scene to OpenCV as a camera?

Comment: What gave you that idea? QGLWidget has a minimum implementation requirement of OpenGL 2.0 / ES 2.0 for certain functionality, but is not limited to either. Basically all QGLWidget does is abstract and hide OpenGL context management from you so you can embed an OpenGL context into your application portably. You can still use native OpenGL bindings once you have the QGLWidget's context active/current within a thread.

Comment: This topic gave me that idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671816/opengl-vs-qopengl-qtopengl-in-qt-5-differences-and-limitations

Comment: That topic is discussing the API wrappers (things that try to make working with FBOs, VBOs, etc. "easier"). QGLWidget is lower-level than that, it merely manages an OpenGL context and lets you use it as a widget within a dialog; once active you can issue any GL command your driver supports.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on all the questions I asked and post it as an answer? Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used OpenCV, so all I can do is comment on OpenGL in Qt. It's not really an answer, so much as a clarification.